# Get suffix of a string

Tags: string, ocaml

I'm looking for a function of the following signature

```
val suffix : t -> int -> t
```

`suffix s n` returns the longest suffix of `s` of length less than or equal to `n`

Does standard String module provide such a function? If yes, how to use it ?

I need to exclude the first character of a string and use the rest i.e, construct a string from the longest proper suffix. Given `"abc"`, I need a string `"bc`". I tried the following, but it failed

```
String.suffix s ((String.length s) - 1)
```

with the following error.

```
Error: Unbound value String.suffix
```

How should I open the module and use it ? `open String` and `open Core.Std` fails.

Expected function signature was copied from [here](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/109.24.00//doc/core/String.html).

Comment: Your test is using the  String module of the OCaml standard library. Your link points to the documentation of a different library named "Core". You can load the Core library into the toplevel and/or compile and link against Core. But you need to do these explicitly because Core is not built in.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield Thanks for the comment. I'm new to OCaml. I don't know how to include the library. Moreover, as *I cannot provide the build command to the build system* myself, I'm afraid I cannot afford to link my code against `Core` library myself. I have to work with whatever is baked into the language. Does the standard `String` library have one like this ? Or should I write a function of my own ?

Comment: Writing your own should be doable using the OCaml standard library `String.length` and `String.sub` ( https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/String.html#VALsub ) functions.

Comment: @Yawar Thanks for pointing this out. It was enough for my use.

`let except_first_char s = 
    try 
    (String.sub s 1 ((String.length s)-1)) 
    with (Invalid_argument "this cannot happen") -> ""`

Answer (score 0):

Using just the `String` and `Seq` modules from the standard OCaml library: get the length of the string, convert the string to a sequence, drop the first character, then drop all but `n` characters. Then convert it back to a string.

```
let suffix s n =
  let len = String.length s in
  s
  |> String.to_seq
  |> Seq.drop 1
  |> Seq.drop (len - n - 1)
  |> String.of_seq
```

```
# suffix "abc" 2;;
- : string = "bc"
# suffix "abcd" 2;;
- : string = "cd"
# suffix "abcd" 3;;
- : string = "bcd"
# suffix "ab" 2;;
Exception: Invalid_argument "Seq.drop".
```

It works! Until it doesn't. We can fix that with a simple check.

```
let suffix s n =
  let len = String.length s in
  if len <= n then 
    "" 
  else 
    s
    |> String.to_seq
    |> Seq.drop 1
    |> Seq.drop @@ len - n - 1
    |> String.of_seq
```

```
# suffix "ab" 2;;
- : string = ""
# suffix "abc" 2;;
- : string = "bc"
```